# Scala way choosing configuration regarding different environment

Tags: scala

My application needs to read configuration file either from the resource directory or from s3.

For local development, I need to read it from the local resource directory.  So, when build my project, I don't put the configuration file `config.properties` into my application jar file.  In this case, it should read the configuration from S3.  When I can think of doing this scala is pretty much like what I do it by java

```
val stream : InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")
if (stream != null) {
  val lines = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream( stream ).getLines
} else {
  /*read it from S3*/
}
```

But I think scala gives a more functional programing sytax.  Any advice?

Comment: How to you differentiate between the local and production environment? It is just a Scala app and not a Playframework app right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways to go about what you're after, but here's a more-or-less straight translation of the posted code.

```
val lines:Iterator[String] = Option(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"))
                            .fold{/*read from S3
                                  return Iterator*/}(io.Source.fromInputStream(_).getLines)
```

Comment: Exactly what I want.  Thanks!